# Disable a device's service from powershell or command line

Tags: audio, powershell, services, control-panel

<sup>Just read the bold text for the basic rundown!</sup>
**I have a bluetooth headset** that I use for gaming, however because it has a mic **I have to disable the "handsfree telephony" service every time I pair the two devices** (Which is frequent as I also use the headset with my phone) otherwise it will play no sound or switch to call mode where it sounds like a bad radio.

**My procedureis as follows:** `Control Panel --> Hardware and Sound --> Devices and Printers --> Right click the headset --> properties --> servies tab --> uncheck "Handsfree Telephony"`.

If I forget to do this I have to close and reopen the game. I also have to restart and videos I'm watching.

Is there a way to **automate disabling a device's service task with powershell or the command prompt**?

Comment: Do you know if this actually stops the service or is it just decoupling the BT device but the service keeps running?

Comment: I have no idea, I know that it can still work on other headsets, and I know that games and such no longer see the device as having the service.

Comment: bottom line, this "services tab" is just a registry entry. Search the registry for the make of the headset. If you can find the hive, there may be a registry with the label handsfree telephony. If you can find that, then it is as simple as running a script the value to a 1 or 0.

Comment: You know, I sometimes forget about the registry. I'll give that a try!

Comment: @Narzard I've found where bluetooth devies are stored and found the registry entry for my specific device, however no changes occur when I toggle that setting. Any ideas as to where it might be?

Comment: I'm in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\BTHENUM`. Things change for its description and name and such, but exporting and loading the registry files before and after changing the setting makes no difference for the functionality.